# Set 'start' and 'end' values of slider range in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

The data I have:

```
head(ave_temp)
         date deadlift
5  2012-12-01       50
6  2013-01-01       62
7  2013-02-01       70
8  2013-03-01       70
9  2013-04-01       77
10 2013-05-01       83
```

from which I create a bar chart with *ggplot2*. To make it interactive I use *ggplotly* and its function *rangeslider*. Then I want to set slider range the way that when you load the chart the time interval you see is f. ex. a few years not all years my data have.

The result I want:

[image: pic2]

The chart my code produces:

[image: pic3]

And my code:

```
ave_temp <- ave[!is.na(ave$deadlift),]

g2 <- ggplot(data = NULL) +
  theme_light() +
  labs( y = 'Deadlift (kg)', x = 'Date') +
  geom_col(data = ave_temp, aes(x = date, y = deadlift, text = paste('Deadlift: ', deadlift)),  fill = "pink", alpha = 1, width =15) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "years" , date_labels = "%Y") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,150,25))

ggplotly(g2, tooltip = c("text"), dynamicTicks = T) %>%
  rangeslider(borderwidth = 1, start = ave_temp$date[5], end = ave_temp$date[14])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please add your data in text form. This would make it easier for people to help you.